# How would i use a nested select statement to find all the people that share the same name as the person with ID 11834

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what i have so far for one person only.
what would would i need to do to find everyone with the same name using the ID

INPUT:

```
SELECT given_name || ' ' || family_name AS "NAME"
FROM customer 
WHERE customer_id = '112524';
```

OUTPUT:

```
James
```

Responses will be much appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1
              from customers c2
              where c2.given_name = c.given_name and c2.family_name = c.family_name
             );
```

I see no particular reason to concatenate the names together to address this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a self join:

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM customer c1 INNER JOIN customer c2
ON c2.given_name = c1.given_name AND c2.family_name = c1.family_name   
WHERE c2.customer_id = '112524' AND c1.customer_id <> '112524'
```

You may remove `AND c1.customer_id <> '112524'` if you want `c1.customer_id = '112524'` in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an analytic function so that you do not need to use a self-join:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       given_name,
       family_name
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         given_name,
         family_name,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN customer_id = '112524' THEN 1 END)
           OVER ( PARTITION BY given_name, family_name ) AS matches_name
  FROM   customer
)
WHERE  matches_name > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer ( customer_id, given_name, family_name ) AS
SELECT 112524, 'James', 'Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112523, 'John',  'Smith' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112522, 'James', 'Small' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112521, 'James', 'Smith' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | GIVEN_NAME | FAMILY_NAME
> ----------: | :--------- | :----------
>      112524 | James      | Smith      
>      112521 | James      | Smith
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca2455d3fec85f3fbf160b952b5f2b09)*

Answer (score 0):

You want nested select then you can use `exists` or `IN`.

```
select c.*
  from customers c
 where (coalesce(given_name,'####'), coalesce(family_name,'####')) in 
       -- nested query starts from here 
       (select coalesce(c2.given_name,'####'), coalesce(c2.family_name,'####')
         from customers c2
        where c2.customer_id = '112524' )
 And c.customer_id  <> '112524' ;
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b37a58b5fe7833aeca0196c848387d8)

Comment: This will not return any rows if one of the values in the `IN` expression list is `NULL` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6243771c15ad7104a3daee82035ec4a).

Comment: Ok, I didnt considered null. Check answer and db<>fiddle now. @MT0

Answer (score 0):

This script shows all persons which share the same name including one of null values.

```
SELECT * FROM customer b  
WHERE b.given_name ||'##'|| b.family_name IN (
    --this is nested query
    SELECT a.given_name ||'##' a.family_name FROM customer a WHERE customer_id = '112524')
AND B.customer_id <> '112524'
```

Comment: If you have the name `ANN ASPEN` then this would also match `ANNA SPEN` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=095e6869718430368aaf695a73e51236).

Comment: Now, I edited code as b.given_name ||'##'|| b.family_name . So, ANN ASPEN is processed as ANN##ASPEN, and ANNA SPEN as ANNA##SPEN . They wouldnt match .